# Extracting Resting State Networks Time Series from NIFTI File (MATLAB)

Tags: fmri

I have plenty of experience in EEG analysis but I have never worked with fMRI. I want to parcellate the fMRI data using the Yeo 7 resting state networks parcellation. I found a NIFTI file about this specific atlas on Fieldtrip Toolbox but I do not know how to go from the 4-D matrix of the functional NIFTI to a 2-D matrix of network activity. While I can do some coding in Python, I would prefer a MATLAB solution. I have seen several toolboxes but I cannot find a straightforward answer/tutorial. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: There's a lot of nuance to this type of work; you probably need to find someone experienced to walk you through it. Not something you can learn from a tutorial, which might tell you how to use particular software but won't get you through all the various decisions to make. It's not quite so straightforward.

Comment: Yeah good points, but the data I found are already preprocessed and in the MNI space. I ended up finding the solution at CONN Toolbox. I just had to load my files, load the Yeo 7 atlas (found in the "otherrois" folder of the toolbox) and then select extract BOLD time series (at the preferences tab). Overall, this is a pretty nice toolbox.

Comment: Ah, yes, a lot easier if the preprocessing is complete.